# caret dummy-vars exclude target

Tags: r, r-caret, lda

How can I use dummy vars in caret without destroying my target variable?

```
set.seed(5)
data <- ISLR::OJ
data<-na.omit(data)

dummies <- dummyVars( Purchase ~ ., data = data)
data2 <- predict(dummies, newdata = data)
split_factor = 0.5
n_samples = nrow(data2)
train_idx <- sample(seq_len(n_samples), size = floor(split_factor * n_samples))
train <- data2[train_idx, ]
test <- data2[-train_idx, ]
modelFit<- train(Purchase~ ., method='lda',preProcess=c('scale', 'center'), data=train)
```

will fail, as the Purchase variable is missing. In case I replace it with `data$Purchase <- ifelse(data$Purchase == "CH",1,0)` beforehand caret complains that this no longer is a classification but a regression problem

Comment: you can just do `data2$Purchase <- data$Purchase` afterwards can't you?

Comment: I tried that - but this seems to distort the result of the matrix. Is it possible to pass the dummyVars from caret directly into the train? as a pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least the example code seems to have a few issues indicated in the comments below. To answer your questions:

- The result of `ifelse` is an integer vector, not a factor, so the train function defaults to regression
- Passing the dummyVars directly to the function is done by using the train(x = , y =, ...) instead of a formula

To avoid these problems, check the `class` of your objects carefully.

Be aware that option `preProcess` in `train()` will apply the preprocessing to all numeric variables, including the dummies. Option 2 below avoid this, be standardizing the data before calling `train()`.

```
set.seed(5)
data <- ISLR::OJ
data<-na.omit(data)

# Make sure that all variables that should be a factor are defined as such
newFactorIndex <- c("StoreID","SpecialCH","SpecialMM","STORE")
data[, newFactorIndex] <- lapply(data[,newFactorIndex], factor)

library(caret)
# See help for dummyVars. The function does not take a dependent variable and predict will give an error
# I don't include the target variable here, so predicting dummies on new data will drop unknown columns
# including the target variable
dummies <- dummyVars(~., data = data[,-1])
# I don't change the data yet to apply standardization to the numeric variables, 
# before turning the categorical variables into dummies

split_factor = 0.5
n_samples = nrow(data)
train_idx <- sample(seq_len(n_samples), size = floor(split_factor * n_samples))

# Option 1 (as asked): Specify independent and dependent variables separately
# Note that dummy variables will be standardized by preProcess as per the original code

# Turn the categorical variabels to (unstandardized) dummies
# The output of predict is a matrix, change it to data frame
data2 <- data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = data))

modelFit<- train(y = data[train_idx, "Purchase"], x = data2[train_idx,], method='lda',preProcess=c('scale', 'center'))

# Option 2: Append dependent variable to the independent variables (needs to be a data frame to allow factor and numeric)
# Note that I also shift the proprocessing away from train() to
# avoid standardizing the dummy variables 

train <- data[train_idx, ]
test <- data[-train_idx, ]

preprocessor <- preProcess(train[!sapply(train, is.factor)], method = c('center',"scale"))
train <- predict(preprocessor, train)
test <- predict(preprocessor, test)

# Turn the categorical variabels to (unstandardized) dummies
# The output of predict is a matrix, change it to data frame
train <- data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = train))
test <- data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = test))

# Reattach the target variable to the training data that has been 
# dropped by predict(dummies,...)
train$Purchase <- data$Purchase[train_idx]
modelFit<- train(Purchase ~., data = train, method='lda')
```

Comment: are you sure that the preProcessing would not be also applied to the categorical variables (that now are dummy variables 1/0)?

Comment: @PepitoDeMallorca That's a valid concern, although not part of the OP's problem. I've updated Option 2 to provide a solution that avoids this